# Spring Data Rest - PersistentEntity must not be null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am trying to Stream results from a Spring Data Rest Call and am getting the error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity` must not be null!

The call works when I do not try to stream the results.  Any insight is appreciated.

Here is the Repository definition:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.xxx.beverage.repository.db2;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.xxx.xxx.model.db2.Vbrk;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface VbrkRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Vbrk, String> {

    Vbrk findOne(String id);

    @RestResource(path="findByKunag")
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM VBRK v WHERE v.KUNAG = :kunag ", nativeQuery=true)
    Stream<Vbrk> findByKunagAndStream(@Param("kunag") String kunag);

    Page<Vbrk> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not unfortunately.